# 'tail -F' behaving unexpectedly on truncated file

Tags: redirect, tail

I'm trying to follow everything written to a log file in a terminal.

In terminal 1 i do:

```
tail  --retry --follow=name /tmp/test_log
```

or alternatively:

```
tail -F /tmp/test_log
```

In terminal 2 i generate test input for `tail` with:

```
for N in $(seq 1 1000);  do echo "$N" > /tmp/test_log; sleep 1; done
```

I do not expect information to get lost in this test case but still I get the following output, missing numbers 20 and 24:

> ```
> tail: /temp/itworks: file truncated
> 18
> tail: /temp/itworks: file truncated
> 19
> tail: /temp/itworks: file truncated
> 21
> tail: /temp/itworks: file truncated
> 22
> tail: /temp/itworks: file truncated
> 23
> tail: /temp/itworks: file truncated
> 25
> tail: /temp/itworks: file truncated
> 26
> tail: /temp/itworks: file truncated
> 27
> ^C
> ```

If, however, in terminal 2 remove the log before re-wrting, like:

```
for N in $(seq 1 1000);  
do  
    rm /tmp/test_log; 
    echo "$N" > /tmp/test_log; 
    sleep 1; 
done
```

I get the following output, which one would expect from that alternative and is not dropping any information over long runs:

> ```
> 1
> tail: ‘/tmp/test_log’ has become inaccessible: No such file or directory
> 2
> tail: ‘/tmp/test_log’ has become inaccessible: No such file or directory
> 3
> tail: ‘/tmp/test_log’ has become inaccessible: No such file or directory
> 4
> tail: ‘/tmp/test_log’ has appeared;  following end of new file
> 5
> tail: ‘/tmp/test_log’ has become inaccessible: No such file or directory
> tail: ‘/tmp/test_log’ has appeared;  following end of new file
> 6
> tail: ‘/tmp/test_log’ has become inaccessible: No such file or directory
> 7
> tail: ‘/tmp/test_log’ has become inaccessible: No such file or directory
> 8
> tail: ‘/tmp/test_log’ has become inaccessible: No such file or directory
> 9
> tail: ‘/tmp/test_log’ has become inaccessible: No such file or directory
> tail: ‘/tmp/test_log’ has appeared;  following end of new file
> 10
> tail: ‘/tmp/test_log’ has become inaccessible: No such file or directory
> tail: ‘/tmp/test_log’ has appeared;  following end of new file
> 11
> tail: ‘/tmp/test_log’ has become inaccessible: No such file or directory
> 12
> tail: ‘/tmp/test_log’ has become inaccessible: No such file or directory
> 13
> tail: ‘/tmp/test_log’ has become inaccessible: No such file or directory
> 14
> tail: ‘/tmp/test_log’ has become inaccessible: No such file or directory
> tail: ‘/tmp/test_log’ has appeared;  following end of new file
> 15
> tail: ‘/tmp/test_log’ has become inaccessible: No such file or directory
> tail: ‘/tmp/test_log’ has appeared;  following end of new file
> 16
> tail: ‘/tmp/test_log’ has become inaccessible: No such file or directory
> 17
> ^C
> ```

**Since i cannot be sure that system logs are removed before being re-written: how can i make the**

```
echo "$N" > /tmp_test_log
```

**version work?**

Comment: Put `rm /tmp/test_log;` at the beginning of the script not inside the loop and should it be `>` or `>>`. Just tested without  `rm` and it works

Comment: Again the `>` overwrites the file so do you really need `rm` again

Comment: I want to be able to follow a log file with NO information LOSS. I don't want to make any assumption on whether the (system) application uses `rm`, `mv`, `>`, or `>>`.  I would think that with using `>`, `rm` would be superfluous but yet that is the only way I found to avoid data loss.

Comment: But this `for N in $(seq 1 1000);  
do  
    echo "$N" > /tmp/test_log; 

done` works without skipping and if I may ask you need the sleep in the script too?

Comment: See the new sample script and test it works without skipping from my end!

Comment: Same question on serverfault: [overwrite - Is there a `tail -f` equivalent for when a file is overwritten (instead of appended to)? - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/116827/is-there-a-tail-f-equivalent-for-when-a-file-is-overwritten-instead-of-appen) -- unfortunately there's no good solution other than repeatedly check every second? ____________________________________________________________________________________________ I notice that this is probably a race condition in `tail`, if the file is truncated a few millisecond before new content is written in then it also work.